# Update column with column in other table?

Tags: ms-access, multiple-columns

I'm new to Stack Overflow and also access. I genuinely hope I could find my answer here. Please note that the question does not fully describe the problem I'm encountering.

The thing is, now I have two tables: `transaction` and `contact_list`. In `transaction`, I have data like this:

T_id | Applicant

1      |   Peter

2      |   Mary

3      |   John

In contact_list, I have data like this

C_id | Applicant

1      | Mary

2      | Peter

3      |  John

I want to replace 
`transaction.Applicant` with `contact_list.C_id`
on condition where `transaction.Applicant = Contact_list.Applicant`

Making the outcome appears like this:

T_id | C_id

1      | 2        '(Peter)

2      | 1        '(Mary)

3      | 3        '(John)

So is it possible to reach my goal through Design View or query? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty simple way of doing it:

1. Design view your Transaction table.  Add a new field [C_id] (presumably as a number-->long data type).
2. Create an update query where you'll join Contact_list.Applicant to Transactions.Applicant and update your new [C_id] field in Transactions to your Contact_list.C_id.

   `UPDATE contact_list 
         INNER JOIN TRANSACTION 
                ON contact_list.applicant = TRANSACTION.applicant 
   SET    TRANSACTION.c_id = [contact_list].[c_id]`

Now you can delete your initial [Applicant] field in [Transactions]